# When does the loop variable in a for loop get updated?

Tags: c, for-loop

Does the loop variable get updated before beginning the `for` loop? or at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop?

I tried to write a test code to figure it out myself, but I'm not sure if it is a suitable test.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) // does i++ happen here
    {
      printf("%d\n", i); // or does it happen after this is executed?
    }

  return 0;
}
```

With this `while` loop, it's clear where the variable updates:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int j;

  j = 0;
  while (j < 5)
    {
      printf("%d\n", j);
      j++; // j updates here
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your test of the `for` is "suitable". Why wouldn't it be? You should see `0` through `4` printed because the 3rd expression in the `for` is performed at the end of the loop. C programming documentation will explain this. There are a jillion references online if you search, but here's just [one example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop). Your `while` example starts with an uninitialized `j` variable.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for catching that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard *ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Information technology -- Programming languages -- C §6.8.5.3/1 The for statement* **(Emphasis Mine)**:

> The statement
>
> `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement`
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the
>   controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the
>   loop body. **The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void
>   expression after each execution of the loop body.** If clause-1 is a
>   declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder
>   of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two
>   expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an
>   expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression.137)

**Therefore the increment is taking place at the end of each iteration of the for loop.**

You can also see this in the following example. A `for` loop most likely is materialized by the compiler like a `goto` statement. Consider the following piece of code:

```
int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  }
}
```

The assembly code produced by this code is:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
.L3:
    cmpl    $4, -4(%rbp)
    jg  .L2
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://goo.gl/trqc8a)

If you focus at `.L3` (i.e., the `for` loop) you'll notice the statement

```
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
```

which is where the increment is taking place (i.e., `++i`). After that command there's the jump back to `.L3` (i.e., next iteration).

Comment: Examining compiler output is not a sure-fire way to determine what is required of the language (i.e. what the standard requires).   It only determines what the particular compiler does.

Comment: @Peter fair enough. I added the standard justification.

Comment: @101010 What is this "standard" that you quote from and where can I find it?

Comment: @gabacabriel You have to buy it from [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853)

Comment: The "standard" refers to the ISO standard that describes the C programming language (and library).   First version is ANSI X3.159-1989 "Programming Language C.".   This was released (same content, minor topping and tailing differences) in 1990 as ISO/IEC 9899:1990, with subsequent updates ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and (in 2011) ISO/IEC 9899:2011.   You can buy copies through www.iso.org.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `i++` will be evaluated after the loop body completes.

Functionally, a for loop of the form

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

is equivalent in effect to;

```
i = 0;
while (i < 5)
{
    {
         printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite what I previously answered, I was speaking nonsense, I recommend that you look at: [postfix and prefix increment operator in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541399/postfix-and-prefix-increment-operator-in-a-for-loop)

Essentially what the above post boils down with regards to your question is that the incrementation occurs at the END of the pass of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    code;
```

is equivalent to

```
expr1;
while (expr2) {
    code;
    expr3;
}
```

So yes, the increment happens after body is completed. Here is the implementation of `strlen`

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
        ;

    return i;
}
```

that would be the same as:

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only differences with  OP `for` / `while` examples are what happens with a `break` or `continue` and scope rules.

```
for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

acts like

```
{
  clause-1;
  while (expression-2) {
    {
      statement;
      // Should the statement contain a `continue` or `break`, then flow jumps as indicated.
      // a `continue` goes to continue_label:
      // a `break` goes to break_label:
   }
    continue_label:
    expression-3;
  }
  break_label:
}
```

The extra outer `{}` needed for scope:  Should `clause-1` be `int x = 1;` that is not the same as

```
  int x = 1;
  while (expression-2) {
```

but like

```
{
  int x = 1;
  while (expression-2) {
```

The innermost `{}` is also needed for scope.  Examine the following code's output sequence and address of the 3 `j`s.

```
int main(void) {
  int j;
  printf("1 %p\n", (void*) &j);
  for (int j = 0; 
       printf("2 %p\n", (void*) &j), j < 3;
       j++, printf("4 %p\n", (void*) &j)) {
    int j;
    printf("3 %p\n", (void*) &j);
  }
  return 0;
}

1 0x28ac1c
2 0x28ac18
3 0x28ac14
4 0x28ac18
2 0x28ac18
3 0x28ac14
4 0x28ac18
2 0x28ac18
3 0x28ac14
4 0x28ac18
2 0x28ac18
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, the increment gets done after every iteration. 
The while loop is more controllable in that and you can do it in whatever place you want!

Comment: Although when possible, `for` loops are preferred because the increment of the loop variable is guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! It's just that while loop is more controllable in this specific thing. I didn't mean that while loop is better. The loop that one will use differs from situation to situation and a lot of times it is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

The `i++` happens after the body of the for loop. According to [the GNU C Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-for-Statement),

> ```
>  for (initialize; test; step)
>    statement
> ```
>
> The for statement first evaluates the expression initialize. Then it
>   evaluates the expression test. If test is false, then the loop ends
>   and program control resumes after statement. Otherwise, if test is
>   true, then statement is executed. Finally, step is evaluated, and the
>   next iteration of the loop begins with evaluating test again.